# Evaluating the impact of US federal grants

Tags: applied-econometrics, time-series, paneldata, usa

There are a number of challenges with evaluating the impact/effectiveness of federal grants in the U.S.

In particular, it's easy to obtain a (somewhat comprehensive) record of transactions between grantors and grantees from websites like https://www.usaspending.gov/#/. However, it's unclear how to determine from that transaction data the amount of federal support at a given point in time, say to a given state. E.g., if a grant is associated with a single $1,000,000 transaction in the middle of the grant's 3 year period of execution, how should we determine the amount og federal support associated with that grant in years 1, 2, and 3?

I am looking for suggestions on how to deal with this issue, as well as examples of papers studying the impact of U.S. federal grants that could give me methodological clues on how to deal with this and other related issues.